# Can Jordan Curve Theorem be applied on Riemann Sphere?

Tags: complex-numbers, plane-curves

For this question I will consider $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{C}$ only to use the Riemann Sphere.

The Jordan Curve Theorem says a jordan curve divides divides the space into a interior region, **bounded** by the curve and the exterior, **unbounded**.

The term bounded means the set is limited (exists a circle which contains all the bounded set).

Clearly a circle (a jordan curve) $x^2+y^2=1$ divides the plane into two regions $S_1$ and $S_2$, and so does the line $y - x= 0$, but both regions are unbounded.

Although the idea of "line divides a plane in two" seems intuitive, I cannot say for sure any curve that goes to infinite in both ways divides a plane in two regions (clearly unbounded).

So, interested of finding a condition to decide if a "infinite" curve divides the plane in two:

**Question:** If I pick a curve and project it in Riemann Sphere, and the resultant curve is a jordan curve, does it means the original curve divides a plane in two? Is the versa true? Are there counter-examples?

For example, the hyperbola $y^2-x^2=1$ is mapped into Riemann Sphere like an $8$-ish shape with the intersection at $\infty$ and therefore this hyperbola divides the plane in three, not in two. A parabola would divide the plane into two regions.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4712221.

Answer (score 1):

The Jordan curve theorem for the plane implies a version of the theorem for the 2-sphere: if $\gamma : S^1 \mapsto S^2$ is continuous and injective with image $\cal I$, then $S^2 \setminus {\cal I}$ is homeomorphic to two open discs. To prove this pick $x \in S^2 \setminus {\cal I}$, take it as the point at infinity and use the resulting stereographic projection to translate the problem into a problem about a continuous injection $S^1 \to \Bbb{R}^2$. Then apply the Jordan curve theorem for the plane and pull your conclusions back along the stereographic projection.

Minor issue: how do we know $S^2 \setminus {\cal I}$ is non-empty? Answer: because $S^1$ and $S^2$ are compact, $\gamma$ maps closed sets to closed sets and hence, if it were surjective, it would be a homeomorphism; but $S^2$ and $S^1$ are not homeomorphic, because removal of two distinct points disconnects $S^1$ but not $S^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my problem is basically when the curve $\gamma$ pass throught the $\infty$ point in Riemann Sphere. The transformation $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ not necessarily is a continuous injection. As example, take $\gamma(t): \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \ \frac{3\pi}{2}\right] \to \left(\cos t, \ 0, \ \sin t\right)$ in the sphere. The projection of every point of $\cal I$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the line $y = 0$, but it's discontinuous when $t = \pi/2$

Comment: But you can just rotate the sphere so the curve misses the point at infinity.